# Is there a good way to extend @types/node/index.d.ts

Tags: typescript

`process._getActiveHandles()` produces an error because not everything was published in `@type/nodes/index.d.ts`.
I have node v8.11.1 and I used `npm install @types/node@9.6.2`.
Should I stop using npm's @types and edit my own copy?

The `@types/node@12.7.5` does not have it in `globals.d.ts` either.

`(<any>process)._getActiveHandles()` of course ignores the error, but I don't want to lose the typo-checking.

`_getActiveHandles()` is just one case.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add custom types to the existing node types. With something like:

```js
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Process {
      _getActiveHandles(arg: number): boolean;
    }
  }
}

process._getActiveHandles = (arg) => !!arg;
const result = process._getActiveHandles(1)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Process {
      _getActiveHandles(): any[];
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks skovy. (I could not get code into the comment.)

Placing this in a separate ts file allowed access to the existing function without complaints from both tsc and Visual Code (although tsc might never have complained???):

```
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Process {
            _getActiveHandles(): any[];
        }
    }
}
```